# How to search Dictionary.com for a word and ONLY extract the first definition?

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup, python-requests

This is my code:

```
import colored
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

inputcolor = colored.fg(2)

headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
    }

url = "https://www.dictionary.com/browse/balance-of-power"
req = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all("div", {"value": "1"}))
```

The reason why I used `soup.find_all("div", {"value": "1"})` is because this is where the first result will be in the site code:

```
<div value="1" class="css-10ul8x e1q3nk1v2"><span class="one-click-content css-nnyc96 e1q3nk1v1" data-term="distribution" data-linkid="nn1ov4">a distribution and opposition of forces among nations such that no single nation is strong enough to assert its will or dominate all the others.</span></div>
```

The code that I have returns this:

```
<div value="1" class="css-10ul8x e1q3nk1v2"><span class="one-click-content css-nnyc96 e1q3nk1v1" data-term="distribution" data-linkid="nn1ov4">a distribution and opposition of forces among nations such that no single nation is strong enough to assert its will or dominate all the others.</span></div>
```

It's close, but it still doesn't print only the definition and nothing else, how could I get it to do that?

Comment: What about `soup.find_all("div", {"value": "1"})[0].get_text()`?

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. Not entirely sure why it works, but you got it to work

Comment: @RJAdriaansen, why not make it an answer, it's a common problem ?

Comment: sure just a sec

Comment: @gfdgfdgdf If you don't know why something works, look it up: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_all` returns a list. So you'll have to get the first list item by index `0`. Then you can extract the text with `get_text()`:

```
soup.find_all("div", {"value": "1"})[0].get_text()
```